# Публикация страницы на GitHub

Tags: github, gulp, сборка

**Всем доброго дня!**

Я создал по макету сайт, используя gulp, scss, html5.
В корневой папке файлы: gulp, node_modules, dist, app.

В папке dist находится готовая сборка проекта: index.html, js, css (из scss получен кроссбраузерный css, который сжат);

В папке app находится проект, с которым я работал (рабочая(нескомпилированная версия)).

Я попытался залить на гитхаб весь проект, но он не даёт это сделать, т.к. там больше чем 100 файлов. Но при этом мне нужно залить весь проект(чтобы был и галп, и scss и т.д.), чтобы работодатель видел, при помощи чего выполнен проект.

Подскажите, как мне следует поступить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую так же не закидывать в гит репозиторий папки node_modules и gulp, так как такие вещи устанавливаются локально и не перетаскиваются с помощью гита

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы успешно протолкнуть большое количество байтов с помощью `git`, скорее всего, вам сначала придется настроить [http.postBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly/64565533#64565533) на большое значение, при котором доступно достаточно свободной системной памяти.